# awk command with regex expression from variable fails

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to fetch elements from array on the basis specific pattern
for example:
**alllist** is array contains following data:

```
echo "${alllist[@]}":
setup-demo1-release-0 setup-demo1-release-1 setup-demo1-release-2 setup-demo1-production-0 setup-demo1-production-1
```

where type is a variable and can have values like **-release-0** and **-production-0** ending with **hyphen** and **numeric number**

**setup-demo1** is same for all elements in array and **<-release-0>** and **<-production-0>**
so created a regex expression in which it will look for something like this:
for **type=release** it shall return all values

```
setup-demo1-release-0 setup-demo1-release-1
```

for **type=production** it shall return all values

```
setup-demo1-production-0 setup-demo1-production-1
```

Note: **setup-demo1** can also be written as setup-release1 or setup-production1 so using grep for these words shall be ignored.

I have also tried achieving this through awk command:

```
endWithDigitPattern='[-0-9]'
targetNodes=($(echo "$alllist"| sed 's/[][",]//g' | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -v nTypes="release""$endWithDigitPattern" '$1~ nTypes {print $1}'))
```

and it is not returning expected result while executed through script file.
and may be I am not using **endWithDigitPattern** variable in right way.

Let me know what's wrong with my command used.

Comment: `alllist` is not an array. It is a scalar holding some string (containing brackets, quotes, commas and alphanumeric characters). If you need a bash array, you would have to convert it first.

Comment: @user1934428 its already converted and updated question.

Comment: Try `endWithDigitPattern='-[0-9]'`.

Comment: @VineyDhiman: Even in the updated question, `alllist` is a scalar; just the content is different.

Comment: @user1934428 corrected.

Comment: You have `alllist` an array, but below, when you calculate _targetNodes_, you treat the variable like a scalar:  `echo "$alllist"| sed ....`. Of course `echo` **does** produce some string on stdout, which is fine, since _sed_ can't process arrays, but is the content really in a format your `sed` pattern can process? Perhaps you should process the array directly instead.

Comment: the regex for a string to end in a digit is `[0-9]$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ alllist=(setup-demo1-release-0 setup-demo1-release-1 setup-demo1-release-2 setup-demo1-production-0 setup-demo1-production-1)
$ endWithDigitPattern='[-0-9]'
```

`echo "$alllist"` is the same as `echo "${alllist[0]}"`; to display the entire contents of the array we need to use `echo "${alllist[@]}"`  (keeping in mind this will not work as expected if the array values contain white space), eg:

```
$ typeset -p alllist
declare -a alllist=([0]="setup-demo1-release-0" [1]="setup-demo1-release-1" [2]="setup-demo1-release-2" [3]="setup-demo1-production-0" [4]="setup-demo1-production-1")

$ echo "$alllist"            # references alllist[0]
setup-demo1-release-0

$ echo "${alllist[@]}"
setup-demo1-release-0 setup-demo1-release-1 setup-demo1-release-2 setup-demo1-production-0 setup-demo1-production-1
```

OP's current code:

```
$ echo "$alllist"| sed 's/[][",]//g' | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -v nTypes="release""$endWithDigitPattern" '$1~ nTypes {print $1}'
setup-demo1-release-0
```

Fix to OP's current code:

```
$ echo "${alllist[@]}"| sed 's/[][",]//g' |tr ' ' '\n' | awk -v nTypes="release""$endWithDigitPattern" '$1~ nTypes {print $1}'
setup-demo1-release-0
setup-demo1-release-1
setup-demo1-release-2
```

---

Assuming we can ignore the possibility of white space within the array values, there are a few other ways to to perform the desired operation; one idea using `printf|grep`:

```
$ type=production
$ printf "%s\n" "${alllist[@]}" | grep -- "-${type}-[0-9]"
setup-demo1-production-0
setup-demo1-production-1

$ type=release
$ printf "%s\n" "${alllist[@]}" | grep -- "-${type}-[0-9]"
setup-demo1-release-0
setup-demo1-release-1
setup-demo1-release-2
```